# How to call a method if event got not fired again

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I wanna call a method in a `TextChanged` event only if the event got not fired again within one second.

How can this be done in `WPF` (maybe using a `DispatcherTimer`)?

I currently use this code but it does not call `MyAction()` within `Method`:

```
bool textchanged = false;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textchanged = true;
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += (o, s) => { Method(); };
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

void Method()
{
    if (!textchanged) //here always false
    {
        //never goes here
        MyAction();
    }
    //always goes here
}
```

Comment: It "never goes here" because `textchanged` is true, hence `!textchanged` is false. That said, you should not create a new DispatcherTimer in each call of `textBox1_TextChanged`. Instead, create the DispatcherTimer once, then only start it in TextChanged, and stop it in `Method`.

Comment: @Clemens yes, I know that but how can I make a working version of my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

void Method()
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    MyAction();
}
```

And add this straight after your `InitializeComponent();` line within your constructor:

```
dispatcherTimer.Tick += (o, s) => { Method(); };
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```